# Compare two dataframes with different format column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes

df1:

| AccountNo | name | a/ctype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.22.21 | Henry | checking |
| 11.22.22 | Sam | Saving. |
| 11.22.23 | John | Checking |

df2:

| AccountNo | name | a/ctype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-22-21 | Henry | checking |
| 11-22-23 | John | Checking |
| 11-22-24 | Rita | Checking |

output:
df3:

| A/cNO_df1 | A/cNO_df2 | result. | Name_df1 | Name_df2 | result | a/ctype_df1 | a/ctype_df2 | result. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.22.21 | 11-22-21 | Match | Henry | Henry | Match. | checking | checking | Match. |
| 11.22.22 |  | Notindf2 | Sam. |  | Notindf2 | checking |  | Notindf2 |
| 11.22.23 | 11-22-23 | Match | John. | john | Match. | checking | checking | Match. |
| . | 11-22-24 | Notindf1 | . | Rita | Notindf1 |  | checking | Notindf2 |

I tried removing the non numeric character for the accounts to compare both data set using:
df1['AccountNo'] = df1.AccountNo.replace(regex=[r'\D+', value='')
df2['AccountNo'] = df2.AccountNo.replace(regex=[r'\D+', value='')

And then concat two dataframes. But, When I remove the character I cannot print it in the same format and for ac not in df1 and ac not in df2 I am not able to concat that. I tried using numpy where to compare and concat.

Is there a way it can be done?

Comment: is `df3` your expected output?

Comment: is it expected to have `MM.DD.YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY` formats? `.`vs `-`

Answer (score 1):

You can merge with an external Series as key:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='AccountNo', right_on=df2['AccountNo'].str.replace('-', '.'),
          suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'), how='outer')
```

output:

```
  AccountNo AccountNo_df1 name_df1 a/ctype_df1 AccountNo_df2 name_df2 a/ctype_df2
0  11.22.21      11.22.21    Henry    checking      11-22-21    Henry    checking
1  11.22.22      11.22.22      Sam      Saving           NaN      NaN         NaN
2  11.22.23      11.22.23     John    Checking      11-22-23     John    Checking
3  11.22.24           NaN      NaN         NaN      11-22-24     Rita    Checking
```

Comment: I am trying something like this
df1['AccountNo'] = df1['AccountNo'].str.replace('-', '')
df['AccountNo'] = df['AccountNo'].str.replace('.', '')
But I am getting the value always in scientific notation like 11+E-4 but I wanted something like this 112221.

Comment: it should also work. Removing the dots/dashes should not convert to float, you must be doing something else